# Is there anyway to change a background image in oxygen builder automatically when its night and day?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I did try this code to change it when its night and sunset image when it's day.
But it's not automatically changing.

```
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();

var sunset_img= "http://at-cdn-s01.audiotool.com/2014/06/03/documents/85NwUJbwC0Gx0rbiKePSWWcKUqhmdP/0/cover256x256-46428e19514b49058125b21b8107c2eb.jpg";
var night_img = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2973095145/47f74748e0c6240db5e0b3034af6da16.jpeg";

if (hours > 6 && hours < 20) {
  document.getElementById('feature_img').setAttribute('src', sunset_img);
} else {
  document.getElementById('feature_img').setAttribute('src', night_img);
}
```

Thank you in advance for the response.

Comment: hi, does it work when you refresh the page? if it does and you want it to automatically change without you having to reload, perhaps you could use `setInterval` to check every n seconds

Comment: Put everything in a function then call with with setInterval() every x seconds as @corn on the cob said :)